# qgis:deletecolumn in QGIS 3 graphical modeler

Tags: qgis-3, algorithm, qgis-modeler, delete

I want to use the algorithm `qgis:deletecolumn` in a graphical modeler.

How do I have to fill the case `Fields to delete` :

- `["field1","field2"]`
- `"field1","field2"`
- `field1,field2`
- `[field1,field2]`

And is there another way to say to QGIS : delete all fields except `field1, field2, ...` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you separate the fields with a semi colon like this:

```
Field1;Field2;Field3
```

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/294691/syntax-for-fields-to-keep-of-intersection-tool-in-graphical-modeler